# When $J$ is uncountable $R^{J}$ is not Normal

Tags: general-topology

So this is an exercise of Munkres,

Let $X=\mathbb{N}^J$ and the first step is to show that if $x \in X$ and $B $ is a finite subset let $U(x,B)$ consist of the element $y$ of $X$ such that $x(\alpha) = y(\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in B$ then $U(x,B)$ is a basis for $X$. I can see that in the subspace topology this is going to be an open set, my problem is that when trying to prove that this is basis for $X$ and when thinking of elements of $X$ as functions from $J$ to $\mathbb{N}$ basically what we are saying is that there is at least an index $\alpha$ where any two functions agree, so after thinking about this i think that this might be possible because $J$ is uncountable and $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, is this the case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to see that these sets form a base; you just need to realise that 
$\Bbb N$ is discrete, it holds for any power of a discrete space:

Suppose $O$ is product open in $X$ and $x : J \to \Bbb N$ is a point of $O$.

Then there is a standard basic open subset $\prod_{\alpha \in J} O_\alpha$
with $x \in \prod_{\alpha \in J} O_\alpha \subseteq O$, so (by definition of the standard base) there is a finite subset $F \subseteq J$ such that $O_\alpha = \Bbb N$ for all $\alpha \notin F$ and all $O_\alpha$ are open.

Now $x(\alpha) \in O_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in J$ so

$$U(x,F) \subseteq \prod_{\alpha \in J} O_\alpha$$

(suppose $y \in U(x,F)$ then for all $\alpha \in F$, $y(\alpha) = x(\alpha) \in O_\alpha$, and for all $\alpha \notin F$, $y(\alpha) \in O_\alpha=\Bbb N$ is obvious, so $y \in \prod_{\alpha \in J} O_\alpha$.)

Finally remark that a set of the form $U(x,B)$ is open in the product because it is exactly of the basic open form $\prod_{\alpha \in J} O_\alpha$ where $O_\alpha = \{x_\alpha\}$ for $x \in B$ and $O_\alpha = \Bbb N$ for $\alpha \notin B$, where we use that all singletons are open in $\Bbb N$ (the discreteness), and $B$ is finite (as required for a basic open set).

Comment: In my initial thought process , i started doing that and playing with the basis of the product topology , but i do have a doubt that is , when we are talking about $U(x,F)$ are we fixing $x$ and just variate $F$ or are  we considering about every point of the space and every finite subset of $J$ we can choose? Because for it to be a basis we need to show that for every $y$ and every open set $U$ such that $y \in U$ we can put a basis element with $y$ inside $U$ , and i cant quite see how to do that with fixing the point $x$ , maybe im just not looking at it right.

Comment: @PedroSantos You are taking **all** sets $U(x,B)$ where $x \in X$ and $B \subseteq J$ finite. That is the base (fixing $x$ it's a local base at $x$ only, so we need to vary $x$ as well, to get a basis everywhere).

Comment: Ah so that was my mistake , i was fixing $x$ so i was really not seeing how that would give me a basis for the whole space , thanks !!